# Ошибка, связанная с созданием telegram bota

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Имеется следующий код простого бота:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('<my_token>')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

При выполнение получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
 2019-02-22 05:13:54,949 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot775211299:AAFSuW6iGVjehfWPgHgFz9gJwh6K_11lFqQ/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6f80e2c>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))",),)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
        (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
        self._validate_conn(conn)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
        conn.connect()
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 301, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
        self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6f80e2c>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot775211299:AAFSuW6iGVjehfWPgHgFz9gJwh6K_11lFqQ/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6f80e2c>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
        task(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 276, in __retrieve_updates
        updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 246, in get_updates
        json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
        return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
        timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
        raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot775211299:AAFSuW6iGVjehfWPgHgFz9gJwh6K_11lFqQ/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6f80e2c>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
    "
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
        (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
        self._validate_conn(conn)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
        conn.connect()
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 301, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
        self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6f80e2c>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot775211299:AAFSuW6iGVjehfWPgHgFz9gJwh6K_11lFqQ/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6f80e2c>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "bot.py", line 12, in <module>
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 389, in polling
        self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 412, in __threaded_polling
        polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 78, in raise_exceptions
        six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
        task(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 276, in __retrieve_updates
        updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 246, in get_updates
        json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
        return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
        timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/home/javacoder/Рабочий стол/folder/webhook/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
        raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot775211299:AAFSuW6iGVjehfWPgHgFz9gJwh6K_11lFqQ/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0xb6f80e2c>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Comment: Сервера Телеграм заблокированы на территории РФ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответе. А как это обойти?

Comment: Использовать VPN или запускать бота не на территории РФ.